# amchart4 label text gets overlapped by other lineseries chart data

Tags: amcharts, gantt-chart, amcharts4

Using amchart4, the legacy version.
I'm working on a Gantt chart which shows some data of activities going on field.

Problem statement :
      Ref Image 1.
I'm trying to show the full title text of the activities to make it more readable.
      But when another activity comes ahead of its text gets overlapped , Also when I change the time frame text gets overlapped by other activities
      I'm now stacking the activities by checking there start and end date.

Expected behavior :
      Ref Image 2.
      What I wanted to achive is , to get the end point location of the title text ends. and from there we can calculate if activity is overlapping it
      same as I achieved (Pushed manually/hardcoded) the title is fully readable and activities are getting stacked below if the text is touching another activity
      
      So somehow, I wanted to get the date or location of the title text dynamic end point, so I can compare it with another activity if it's overlapping it
The main intent behind this is to show the full text without overlapping the things and messing the core functionality of Gantt chart

Image 1 :[This is like it messing up by overlapping the things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWQwg.png)
Image 2 :[This is what I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExL10.png)